# Updating joomla 1.7 to 2.5.X - Can't see the package

Tags: php, joomla

Updating joomla 1.7 to 2.5.X but when I try to find the updated version via backend admin panel. I don't see any updates found.

I have checked a number of websites and most of them update joomla via backend extension manager using find updates and install feature but I do not see any update

Comment: Did you click the "Purge Cache" button before trying to find updates?

Comment: a number of times..I have tried to do things manually, got zip files from repo and extracted,,I have upgraded from 1.5 to 1.7 so far.

Comment: And on the Update page, if you click the "Options" button, what is the update type? Stable, beta, alpha?

Comment: Can't see anything like that..

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest you to update to Joomla 3 since Joomla! 2.5 has reached the End of Support.

However, [check this out.](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Updating_Joomla_(Update_Method)) It's a step by step on how to update to joomla 2.5. I am sure there hundreds of tutorials available if you google it. :)

Of course, before doing anything, BACKUP your installation!